# How can I have different HTML pages called conditionally so that linked css and js come along using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a mini system that should show different pages, depending on the user's behavior. A new page will replace the current by changing `document.body.innerHTML = getNewPageContent("AP")`.

When the user calls that web app url, this function below checks if there is a cookie with a token and will have the user logged in automatically. The key part with the issue seems to be the piece that calls the server-side function that serves the new page, whose js functions are not executable. If I open that page directly, the functions are executable.

```
function checkAutoLogin() {
      // Try to find and retrieve the "seo_login_string" cookie
      const storedLoginString = getCookieValue('seo_login_string');
      if (storedLoginString) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(validSession) {
            console.log("Type of client returned: " + JSON.stringify(validSession))

            if (validSession === "C" || validSession === "AP") {
            console.log("New Page called successfully.");  
            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function(newPageContent) {
              document.querySelector('#wp').innerHTML = newPageContent;
              //[...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(o => new Function(`return function(){${o.innerText}}()`)());
              //[...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(o => eval(o.innerText));
              console.log("New Page content fetched and set successfully.");
            })
            .getNewPageContent(validSession);
            }
          })
          .checkLogin("session check", storedLoginString); // Pass the parsed storedSession as an object
      }
    }
```

This is the function invoking the page:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const key = e.parameter.key;

  if (key) {
    // Check if key exists before splitting
    const urlKeys = key.toString().split('-');
    const urlTab = urlKeys[0];
    let agency = urlKeys[1];
    if (agency) {
      agency = agency.toString().replace(/_/g, ' ');
    }
    if (urlTab === 'webApp') {
      const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Login");
      return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `newPageContent` structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>SEO</title>
</head>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ap_dashboard_css').getContent(); ?>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ap_dashboard_js').getContent(); ?>
<body>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <div class="logo-name-wrapper">
      <div class="logo-name">
        <img src="" width="110px" class="logo" alt="logo app" srcset="" />
        <span class="logo-name__name"></span>
      </div>
      <span class="logo-name__button">
          <i class="bx bx-arrow-from-right logo-name__icon" id="logo-name__icon"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <ul class="features-list">
      <li class="features-item list-ul active">
        <div class="ap-btn">
          <div id="apIcon" style="display:inline-flex">
            <i class='bx bx-list-ul features-item-icon' ><span class="status"></span></i>
            <!-- <i class="bx list-ul features-item-icon list-ul"><span class="status"></span></i> -->
            <button class="features-item-button" id="ap-list-btn">Agency Partners</button>
          </div>
          <span class="tooltip">APs</span>
          <div id="nested-list"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin:30px auto">
      <div id="carbon-block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `ap_dashboard_css` file gets applied to the new page shown and
`ap_dashboard_js` comes with the structure, but the functions are not executable.
Within `ap_dashboard_js`, I have the functions wrapped into:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
})
```

Would this mean I will have to have `css` and `js` functions in the `ap_dashboard.html` file?

If you feel like having a glance at it:

[Here is the webApp url to be called](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxccLR4AyeX-ouubO4G_IVQJ7WzPuNWmv1Jcrul1D4FhBzeOOH8GrBx_OT_sMHDWJO_/exec?key=webApp)

[Here is the file itself with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1McB5FyfAwO14S-m5vEZBhVWVR-pAyuGGCceb6xGYs_w/edit?usp=sharing)

user: antoniosan0@hotmail.com
pwd: 123

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. In your showing script, it seems that `getNewPageContent(page)` is Google Apps Script. But, you say `A new page will replace the current by changing document.body.innerHTML = getNewPageContent("AP").`. Is this Javascript which is not Google Apps Script? You are trying to directly run Google Apps Script at Javascript? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide more information for correctly understanding your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have added the client-side function I run that calls `getNewPageContent()` to the question above, @Tanaike ! Thanks for your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine your whole script. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. For example, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between `document.body.innerHTML = getNewPageContent("AP")` and your added script?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation and script, I proposed a modified script using your added script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between `document.body.innerHTML = getNewPageContent("AP")` and your added script `checkAutoLogin()`. But, if you didn't use `document.body.innerHTML = getNewPageContent("AP")` and you are using your added script `checkAutoLogin()`, how about the following modification?

I think that the Javascript copied by `innerHTML` cannot be executed. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, in my modification, the copied Javascript is run after the Javascript was copied.

#### Modified script:

```js
// Check for auto-login on page load
function checkAutoLogin() {
  // Try to find and retrieve the "seo_login_string" cookie
  const storedLoginString = getCookieValue('seo_login_string');
  if (storedLoginString) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function (validSession) {

        if (validSession === "C" || validSession === "AP") {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function (newPageContent) {
              document.body.innerHTML = newPageContent;

              // I added the below script.
              [...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(o => new Function(`return function(){${o.innerText}}()`)());

              // or
              // [...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(o => eval(o.innerText));

            })
            .getNewPageContent(validSession);
        }
      })
      .checkLogin("session check", storedLoginString);
  }
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `newPageContent` includes the `<script>` tag. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When the web app is accessed, it first checks if the user is logged. If so, it automatically calls the new page - that's why we have the `checkAutoLogin()` function. The issue is that the `newPageContent` is load, but not the js file is links to via `<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ap_dashboard_js').getContent(); ?>`. I see the `js` functions in the resulting `HTML` structure, but they are not executable. I've added the `HTML` file of the `newPageContent`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual script, when my proposed script is used, when `document.body.innerHTML = newPageContent` is run, the script of `<script>` tag is executed. In this case, `newPageContent` is required to be the evaluated HTML. From your showing script, I guessed that when `getNewPageContent` is run with `page === "AP"` of true, the evaluated HTML is returned.

Comment: @onit But you say `but not the js file is links to via <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ap_dashboard_js').getContent(); ?>`. I'm worried that your actual script might be different from your showing script. How about this? Unfortunately, I have only the information you gave. So, I cannot correctly imagine your actual script. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @onit By the way, when I tested my proposed script, when `newPageContent` is the evaluated HTML from the template HTML, I confirmed that the loaded Javascript could be executed. I apologize for this situation. So, in your current issue, in order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide a simple script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I have added the url for the web app, as well as for the hosting file and the credentials used (dummy data). Cannot thank you enough for your help.

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet and your script, it seemed that your showing script in your question was different from your provided script. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. Your provided script is large and complicated. And also, it seems that when the HTML is loaded, `checkAutoLogin` has already been run. By this, the empty value of `newPageContent` is loaded. In this case, my proposed script cannot be used.

Comment: @onit But, I think that your question is to execute the loaded Javascript by `document.body.innerHTML = newPageContent`. So, I answered this. I think that my answer can be used for this situation. But, in your whole script, several issues are included. I think that if you want to resolve these issues, you should post them as multiple questions. So, I would like to resolve your issues in order.

Comment: @onit First, how about resolving your this question? In this case, please provide a simple sample script using your showing script in your question. In that case, I think that my answer can be used. Can you provide a simple sample script for using your showing script? If you can cooperate to resolve your issues, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I have modified the question above with the scripts I am working with. Thank you!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. About the execution of the loaded Javascript by `document.body.innerHTML = newPageContent`, I have already posted an answer. Please confirm it. If my answer was not useful, I apologize. By the way, can you provide a simple sample script?

Comment: I did reset my project and used your approach. It worked! Thank you - once again!