# How to have event listeners added functions to loaded js file correctly "reaching" the element using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using this [master's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342276/11832197), I was able to get functions in an Apps Script based js file working on the page. However, if I add an event listener like below, it will not execute:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const dashboardContainer = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
  if (dashboardContainer) {
    dashboardContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dashboardContainer.classList.toggle("activeBtn");
    });
  }
});
```

...but if I do it this way, building and calling the function afterwards, it works:

```
function addEventListenerToDashBtn() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const dashboardContainer = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
    if (dashboardContainer) {
      dashboardContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
        dashboardContainer.classList.toggle("activeBtn");
      });
    }
  });
}
addEventListenerToDashBtn();
```

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the first one into a window.onload = anonymous function then after the page is rendered the the onload event fires and you can add your event listeners forr elements that have already been rendered.

Comment: Actually, for this specific case, it does't work either. No errors thrown, though. I will stick to the second option I layed out above. Thanks!

Comment: But if it's occurs before the onLoad then the element will not be there to attach to.